# Android Studio - build problems after switching JDK to version 1.10

Tags: java, android-studio

I ran into an issue after upgrading the JDK from 1.8 to 1.10 in Android Studio. I also know, that the problem appears in 1.9. When I build my project, it gives me the following errors:

```
error: cannot access ViewGroup class file for android.view.ViewGroup not found error: cannot access Activity class file for android.app.Activity not found
error: cannot access ComponentCallbacks class file for android.content.ComponentCallbacks not found
error: cannot access Application class file for android.app.Application not found
error: cannot access DialogInterface class file for android.content.DialogInterface not found
```

I'm using OpenJDK version from http://jdk.java.net/java-se-ri/10

My path to the JDK directory is as follows:
[JDK path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdxFz.png)

When I switch back to 1.8 (check "Use embedded JDK") in the project structure window, everything works just fine.

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: This also happend to me, but I do not need to switch back the JDK, it is enough to switch back in build.gradle to 1.8, 1.9 does not work:

sourceCompatibility 1.8
targetCompatibility 1.8

Comment: Have you found a solution?  I am experiencing the same thing.

Comment: I am too experiencing the same thing... did you find a solution? @Cb32019

Answer (score 6):

It's a plugin issue.
Either download the Android Studio Canary build from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview).

OR

Download the latest IntelliJ version.

- update the classpath in build.gradle to: 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0-alpha12'
- update build tools version to: '31.0.0 rc2'
- update SDK version to: 30

I'd say go for the second option.